# How to change window border in Awesome WM?

Tags: window, border, awesome-wm

So, I just want to change the ugly default window border in Awsome WM, How do I do ?

Thanks for the answer !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its in your theme.lua. Try looking for variables...

```
theme.border_width = dpi(some number)
theme.border_normal = #some color
theme.border_focus = #some color
theme.border_marked = #some color
```

I believe these can also be set in rc.lua but can't remember, still, best to do it in theme to keep things from getting messy. It might help if do some youtubing on theming AwesomeWM.